# Expanding the cell based on the web-content same like Skype iOS application

Tags: swift, ios10, expand, web-content

I have a requirement where I need to create the UI same like Skype iOS application for display the web-content.

For that I used the `UICollectionViewCell` to accomplish the task but couldn't get the idea how I can expand the size of cell based on the web content.

For more information please find the below link of the screenshot.

[Expanding cell preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W20Di.png)